# Which server is best for asp.net web app. MSSQL Server or SQL server or mysql?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql, vb.net

I am creating web site and want to confirm that which back end i have to use for storing the data.

Comment: MSSQL Server and SQL server are the same.

Comment: okay then tell me sql or mysql???

Comment: There is no definite answer. Both work, although SQL Server might be integrated a bit better into the ASP.NET stack is it also comes from Microsoft. But that really depends on the actual technologies you are using. Voted to close.

Comment: I'd go with microsoft since you're developing in ASP.net

Comment: @ Daniel Hilgarth user answer is accurate.... i have created the connection in asp.net for mssql server 2008... but instead of using full database path i just want to type database name bczzz in any server path can be flexible.... and my conection string is   <add name="cs" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; database=C:\Image Upload Demo\test.mdf; Trusted_Connection=Yes; Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's no matter in how the server best. But it's matter on how the best your skill on the server. The most good skill, the most good the Server DB will be made. Also according to Website ranking from world. We can see that [link](http://www.serverwatch.com/article.php/3883441) show that most best server. Also you can try googling to see Which database server is most good.
Of course, if you don't have the skill, even how good the database, it won't good at all

Answer (score 0):

If you not expert/DBA in any, got MS SQL - it have much better default configuration. Mysql server require some tunning for anything above trivial query(increase different buffers).

Comment: I m using MS SQL 2008 Server